# How can i find character number except space between words

Tags: swift, xcode

My string value is shown below

```
let str = "Hello I m iOS developer"
```

if I wanted to count character in str I can find like this :

```
print(str.utf16.count) // 23
```

But in this solution code block counting space to. But I want to find just character number.Is there any simple code just counting characters?

Comment: I have no experience with Swift at all, but after doing a little bit research I suppose you could try `print(str.components(separatedBy: " ").joined(separator: "").utf16.ccount)` Basically you split the string into an array separated by the space char, then join it again into a string without the space char and count the chars.

Comment: `let cleaned = str.filter({ $0.isLetter || $0.isNumber })`? But, then, what do you expect? And if there is an emoji? `四` character (It's a 4) will be counted as accepted, but if you use `utf16.count`, or just `count`, the number output will be different.

Comment: `let letters = str.reduce(0) { $1.isLetter ? $0 + 1 : $0 }` // 19. To count all characters that is not white spaces `let notWhitespaces = str.reduce(0) { $1.isWhitespace ? $0 : $0 + 1 }`

Comment: there was a question about that. I just wondered how to find it without using separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    let str = "Hello I m iOS developer"
    let filter = str.filter {!$0.isWhitespace}
    print(filter.count)
```